# Kube pod running on systemd-coredump

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, k3s

I am learning Kubernetes an trying to deploy an environment.
Everything is working fine but on my server I find strange the pod running postgresql

I don't have any strange logs messages, or anything. I try to find more info, but maybe I need some verbose parameter on my k3s instance ?

I will say, if it's work, it should be normal, but... is it ?

[linux output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPwKY.png)

I tried to change the permissions in the server-side, a `chown` to another user, delete/create folder, but I got always the same result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please explain with more detail why you find your pod "strange". And I also can't really understand what exactly is your problem?
You can always get more details about pods with `kubectl describe  pod <pod-name>` and `kubectl logs <pod-name>`

Comment: @OberwalderSven I find strange that the postgresql pod is running on a "systemd-coredump" user